# a function code meet 1064 error in mysql 5.7.21

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `nvl`(`expr1` text,`expr2` text) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
     RETURN case when expr1 = '' or expr1 is NULL then expr2 ELSE expr1 end case
END ;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

still, reports :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case
>   END' at line 3`

Why? I can not figure out...

Answer (score 1):

When you say `end case`, you're using the syntax for a [`case` *statement*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html).
What you want is a [`case` *expression*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html), which is terminated with just `end`.

Comment: i notice that the case syntax in 5.7 could allow case when search_condition... in my case.

Comment: That was just the first manual i came to. Any version since about 5.0 should recognize the same distinction. The statement version doesn't allow naked expressions inside, and the expression version doesn't allow naked statements.

Comment: we try to reconstruct the code logic and avoid to use case statement replace with if statement. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra "case" at the end.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `nvl`(`expr1` text,`expr2` text) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
     RETURN case when expr1 = '' or expr1 is NULL then expr2 ELSE expr1 end;
END ;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: the error still exist. i think the case syntax is correctly in 5.7, it may be tail with end case. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: @JarodSun: *Another* error exists. It's not the same one. And no, you don't get to use `end case` here.

Comment: i put a semicolon at the end of case statement; will you retry?

Comment: yes, i try to add semicolon with end or end case, the result is same.